# How to return string value instead of the key from a switch case in a function with enum as return type?

Tags: typescript, types, enums

I have a function that is returning a enum value as type based in other enum cases, is working for one specific case, how can I retrieve the string value for default case; right now is returning the key?

Enums:

```
enum Animal {
  Dinosaur = 'dino',
  Dog = 'dog',
  Cat = 'cat',
  Fish = 'fish',
}


enum Dino {
  Trex = 't-rex',
  Triceratops = 'triceratops',
}
```

Function:

```
const getAnimal = (type: string): Animal {
 switch(type) {
   case Dino.Trex:
   case Dino.Triceratops:
      return Animal.Dinosaur;
   default:
       // if I used an object.keys in order to return the value, I am getting error in the type
       return Animal[type];
 }
}

let aType: Animal;

aType = getAnimal('t-rex');
console.log(aType);

aType = getAnimal('fish');
console.log(aType);

aType = getAnimal('dog');
console.log(aType);

aType = getAnimal('triceratops');
console.log(aType);
```

Output

```
"dino"
"Fish"
"Dog"
"dino"
```

Only the "dino" value is acceptable for the example base in the enum type (Animal) as well, the others are keys instead of the value. What is the properly way to return value from key trying to not return a value as string, in the Tslint is throwing an error that is saying that Type '"value"' is not assignable to type 'Animal', so this way I cannot return mapped value from the enum.

[Sample without the Tslint verification](https://jsfiddle.net/Tabares/crf846ph/7/)

Comment: Currently output will be `dino` `undefined`, `undefined`, `dino`, because you're trying to access enum with a value instead of key (e.g. `'fish'` instead of `'Fish'`)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbKBvAUFKAReIA9gM5JgBOUAvFAOQAmBhtANNnoQObV31evsAwkgAuPWgGNRAnADF4xABbiAZgsUCAvph2hIeJhnYAVcsAAe4kQFoz5mVFPwJwcqMIAHYlfLPX7ry0dCUIQYjFOYBE4RFQeAAoRAE8PYAAuKHDfEE4ASgyY5DQsTIB3eBEJRUSU4FyjHCgpYmADIgA6Uws09iakFrbCTt8XNxFPYh7GxrMRChBYBCL2-CJSCgBuXvpgFTIUESnpnAB6E6h4FSgASSgwFvooJAXCACMAK2AJEXaAa2Akt4CFBCOQdpRxlBZvMoCJFK0AG6oMDAFg3J7QSIiEQEbiucigi4LOGtZKpXrTaHkBaFVAAbTJwAAulsoNptJgUFEnsZagUlqgtpgkLzUjwsbSUPFaDY7LRclsQmFCFz2iguPERbUFTotWKaBKBVLaGolPLFaFiCrgGqNXq6kL7eKopLpXxOObMEqrar1ZxNaKHbrA87okbpSIRv5xoEdd7rbb-faFUA

Comment: Yes, please consider making this into a [mcve] so that people can see what you're seeing.